# Arcgis python： parameter not changed leads to a dead loop

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7

**Requirement Analysis：**
 I have got a Tin/Terrain file, and I set an initial water level, the target is to calculate the volume of this place under the initial water level using the Terrain file. Comparing the volume with the actual value, I got the ideal water level.

**Tools:** Arcgis 10.1 (polygon volume_3D module) python 2.7

**code:**

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "G:/0arcpy/hjh_split"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

inSurface = "G:/0arcpy/hjh_tin"
zField = "sswl" 
refPlane = "BELOW" 
sAreaFld = "SArea"
volFld = "Volume" 

for fc in fclist:    
    arcpy.PolygonVolume_3d(inSurface, fc, zField, refPlane, volFld, sAreaFld) 
    rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc) 
    for row in rows:
        i = row.getValue("Volume") 
        j = row.jyvol 
        while ((abs(i-j))/j>0.1) : 
            row.setValue("sswl",row.getValue("sswl")+0.01)
            rows.updateRow(row)
            arcpy.PolygonVolume_3d(inSurface, fc, zField, refPlane, volFld, sAreaFld)
        print "i="+str(i)+"-"+"sswl="+str(row.sswl)           
        print "Finished"
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Question:**
 The water level(sswl) is changed with plus 0.01, but The i(volume) value is not changed leading to dead loop. But why the value i = row.getValue("Volume") is not changed in the loop. What's the problem and how to change the code?

Comment: Are you attempting to find level to match known volume?

Comment: Yes. You're right. It's my idea.

Comment: There are plenty of ways that level can be unchanged when increasing fill volume (that's the point of emergency spillways, after all) Your modeling code should handle both the no change and negative change conditions correctly

Answer (score 2):

I used single point with Z=0 m and line representation of 100 m buffer around it with Z=100 m, to create TIN. I set polygons to calculate volumes equal same 100 m buffer around the point.

[image: Inputs]

Script below applies bisect method to compute with reasonable precision levels to match predefined target volumes (last column it polygons' table):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
# Set Local Variables
inSurface = r"C:\FELIX_DATA\TIN"
inPoly = r"C:\FELIX_DATA\SCRARCH\POLYGONS.shp"
zField = "sswl";refPlane = "BELOW";
volFld = "Volume";sAreaFld = "SArea"
targetVolume="TARGET_V"
singleLine=r"in_memory\pgon"
d=arcpy.Describe(inPoly)
fidName=d.OIDFieldName
LOW,HIGH,precision=0.0,100.0,0.005

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inPoly,(fidName,"Shape@",zField,volFld,sAreaFld,targetVolume)) as cursor:
    for fid,shp,z,vol,s,targetV in cursor:
        whereclause = """%s = %s""" % (arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(inPoly, fidName),fid)
##      create single feature to play with
        arcpy.Select_analysis(inPoly, singleLine, whereclause)
##      apply bisect to find matching level
        low,high,iterations=LOW,HIGH,0
        while True:
            mid=(high+low)/2
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(singleLine,zField) as uCur:
                for row in uCur:uCur.updateRow((mid,))
            arcpy.PolygonVolume_3d(inSurface, singleLine, zField, refPlane, volFld, sAreaFld)
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(singleLine,[volFld,sAreaFld]) as sCur:
                for row in sCur:v,s=row
            iterations+=1
            if (high-mid)<precision:break
            if v>targetV:high=mid
            else:low=mid
        arcpy.AddMessage('It took %i iterations to find match for polygon %i'%(iterations,fid))
        cursor.updateRow((fid,shp,mid,v,s,targetV))
```

OUTPUT:

[image: Output table]

According to [cone volume formulae](https://www.google.co.nz/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cone%20volume%20formula) results are very close to theory.